# Disentangling 2 unknowns using linear regression

Tags: math, statistics, regression, linear-regression, linearmodels

I am figuring out how to disentangle two unknown values using regressions, and I want to ask whether it is possible.

Let's say I have a measured value (y-axis) that is a sum of two unknowns (A and B).
The sum of two unknowns has an underlying relationship with X, another measured value.

However, we know that A is constant, so it does not change with X, but B does vary.

If a linear regression satisfies A + B ~ X, is there a way to estimate A and B?

It might not be possible at all, but if we know that B varies with X, there might be a way around interpreting the intercept and the gradient to separate A and B...

This is a graph from what I am looking at: [Relationship between A+B ~ X](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2DBxV.png)

The intercept is-0.08 and the gradient is 0.02

It would be extremely helpful if there are any suggestions for additional information required to separate A and B.

Thank you

Comment: I don't see how you can know this a priori.